# No Objective-C?

Tags: support, syntax-highlighting

I'm getting syntax highlighting for `c` and `cpp`, but not `objc` or `objective-c`. Compare:

```c
const char *lang_name = "c";
```

```cpp
std::string langName = "cpp";
```

```
NSString *kLangName = @"objc";
```

```
NSString *kLangName = @"objective-c";
```

Am I using the wrong language name, or is Objective-C syntax highlighting not available?

Comment: [See this post](https://languagedesign.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/15/is-it-me-or-does-syntax-highlighting-not-work), it hasn't been activated yet.

Comment: @Starshipisgoforlaunch That doesn’t explain it, because if that were the case it wouldn’t work for C or C++ either.

Comment: @Starshipisgoforlaunch it *[is](https://languagedesign.meta.stackexchange.com/a/116/66)* activated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Syntax highlighting is somewhat counterintuitive when coming from other established sites. With some exceptions, the short form of highlighting specifications normally rely on the existence of a tag and the tag languages being set when the tag doesn't match a known lang- identifier.

The approach that will always work regardless of site or tag language is to use the full qualified language identifier; these all start with a `lang-` prefix.

According to [What is syntax highlighting and how does it work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/184109/1099857), the objective c identifiers are:

> **Objective-C: `lang-objectivec`**, (`lang-mm`, `lang-objc`, `lang-obj-c`, `lang-obj-c++`, `lang-objective-c++`)

See the working samples below:

````
``` lang-objectivec
NSString *kLangName = @"objective-c";
```
````

```objectivec
NSString *kLangName = @"objective-c";
```

````
``` lang-objc
NSString *kLangName = @"objective-c";
```
````

```objc
NSString *kLangName = @"objective-c";
```